# Erro Msg 8114 no SQL Server ao realizar consulta

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Estou com um problema ao executar uma *query* no *SQL Server*, onde tento trazer uma coluna com uma conversão de feita numa coluna tipo `DATE` e outra coluna com um código HTML montado.

Segue a consulta abaixo:

```
select convert(varchar, R.Data, 121) , '</td><td>' + C.No + '</td><td>' + C.Nome
    + '</td><td>' + V.IdVendedor + '</td><td>' + V.Vendnm + '</td></tr>'
    From dbo.Reclamacoes R 
    Inner Join dbo.PHC_CLIENTES_SAMSYS C On R.IdCliente = C.Id
    Inner Join dbo.PHC_VENDEDORES_SAMSYS V on R.IdVendedor = V.IdVendedor
```

É exibido o erro abaixo

> erro converting data type varchar to numeric Msg 8114, Level 16, State
>   5, Line 1

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Informe a mensagem completa para que possamos te ajudar

Comment: Erro de convesão de tipo , segundo uma pesquisa , veja este "convert" ...

Comment: Aparece o "erro converting data type varchar to numeric" na primeira linha do código.

Comment: @Sorack, o Miguel me mandou um e-mail( [Img1](https://imgur.com/a/MbyQUFe), [Img2](https://imgur.com/a/oyGWBXL) )  pedindo ajuda sobre o seu problema, ao fazer algumas perguntas para ele, consegui ajudá-lo via *hangouts*, porém, achei bacana trazer o caso para o SOpt caso alguém tenha o mesmo problema **Msg 8114** no SQL Server esse post sirva da solução. Se vocês acharem válido reabrir essa pergunta, postarei minha resposta que usei pra solucionar o problema dele.

Comment: @AndréFilipe acho válido sim, inclusive já redigi uma resposta, porém é necessário que mais pessoas votem para reabertura

Comment: Tranquilo @Sorack, fiz uma edição da pergunta dele explanando melhor o seu caso. Agradeço o *feedback*.

Comment: @AndréFilipe obrigado pela edição. sou novo no sql, e só quero aprender o mais rápido possível, porém não sou bom a explicar-me e peço desculpa por isso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando comecei à analisar sua *query*:

1. Achei que poderia ter algo errado com `CONVERT(VARCHAR, r.data, 121)` por conta de não existir um `lenght`(opcional), dei uma pesquisada(apesar de não ter nada errado aqui), achei bacana uma [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74385/how-to-convert-datetime-to-varchar) do [@Colin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/150342/colin) no *stackoverflow.com* sobre os resultados de estilizações(terceiro parâmetro dessa função, `style`) possíveis no `CONVERT()`, uma informação muito interessante.
2. Como o [@Sorack](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/59479/sorack) comentou em sua resposta, o *SQL Server* não permite fazer a concatenação de [data_types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_type) diferentes, no seu caso, a [concatenação](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GCEU_pt-brBR820BR820&q=Dicion%C3%A1rio#dobs=concatenar) de `VARCHAR` com tipo `INTEGER`, por isso, é necessário transformar todos eles em um único tipo para que o seu banco de dados não levante exceção, utilizei o próprio `CONVERT()`, para modificar todos os tipos de dados usados em sua concatenação para o tipo caractere.

   ```
   SELECT convert(nvarchar(MAX), R.Data, 121) AS DATA,
        '</td><td>' + convert(nvarchar(MAX), C.No) + '</td><td>' + C.Nome + '</td><td>' + convert(nvarchar(MAX), V.IdVendedor) + '</td><td>' + convert(nvarchar(MAX), V.Vendnm)+'</td></tr>' AS tabela_HTML
   FROM dbo.Reclamacoes R
   INNER JOIN dbo.PHC_CLIENTES_SAMSYS C ON R.IdCliente = C.Id
   INNER JOIN PHC_VENDEDORES_SAMSYS V ON R.IdVendedor = V.IdVendedor
   ```

Vale lembrar que se você não adicionar um *alias* `AS` para sua coluna, a nomeclatura da coluna virá um pouco confusa.

Entenda mais sobre a função CONVERT() [aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_convert.asp).

Comment: Muito obrigado André Filipe! Por ter editado a resposta e ter resolvido o seu problema. Recomendo muito quem tiver dificuldade nesta tema a seguir-se por esta resposta.

Answer (score 2):

O problema é que você está tentando concatenar algum campo que é um numérico sendo assim o SGBD tenta converter o restante do texto para numérico ao tentar **somar** e não concatenar. Para que este problema não aconteça você deve dizer ao SGBD que os campos numéricos devem ser transformados em `VARCHAR`. Não sei quais campos da sua `query` não são texto, portanto "chutei" quais seriam. Mesmo que não sejam os que sugeri, a essência é a mesma.

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, r.data, 121),
       '</td><td>' + CAST(c.no AS VARCHAR) + '</td><td>' + c.nome + '</td><td>' + CAST(v.idvendedor AS VARCHAR) + '</td><td>' + CAST(v.vendnm AS VARCHAR) + '</td></tr>'
  FROM dbo.reclamacoes r
 INNER JOIN dbo.phc_clientes_samsys c ON r.idcliente = c.id
 INNER JOIN dbo.phc_vendedores_samsys v ON r.idvendedor = v.idvendedor
```

Comment: Agradeço Sorack por ter perdido o seu tempo a tentar ajudar-me, mas porém a resposta do @AndréFilipe me resolveu o problema. Valeu

Comment: Não não Miguel Meireles, não existe tempo perdido quando o assunto é compartilhar conhecimento. Temos de agradecer pela disponibilidade do @Sorack, apenas. Abraços jovem!