# Como retirar o caracter especial que se forma dentro de uma String no SQL?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Estou utilizando o trecho abaixo no meu código, porém na hora de inserir o > dentro de uma String, o mesmo retorna o resultado como &gt ;, o mesmo está convertendo para entidade de HTML, como posso utilizar o '>', sem problemas?

```
'"name":"'+RTRIM(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),CAT.DESCRICAO))+ '>' + CATP.DESCRICAO + '"}',','
```

Resultado do select:

> [{"code":"182574","name":"SMARTPHONE &gt ; TELEFONIA"}]

Comment: Já tentou a sequencia de escape \U02C3?

Comment: Infelizmente é impossível reproduzir o problema somente com o trecho de código que você informou. Forneça um exemplo mínimo executável para que possamos ajudá-lo com sua dúvida

Comment: Você pode informar o seu `SELECT` completo?

Comment: Vale lembrar que o *SQL-Server* não permite concatenar valores que não são do mesmo *data_type*, caso não saiba, aconselho dar uma olhada nesse [conteúdo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/360707/erro-msg-8114-no-sql-server-ao-realizar-consulta/360873#360873) relacionado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi o problema utilizando o '›', achei esse carácter no mapa de caracteres do Windows, o mesmo resolveu o meu problema.